# Regular graphs for fixed number of nodes

Tags: graph-theory

I am beggining to study some graph theory and I have the following question:

For k-regular graphs with a fixed number of nodes, let's say $n$, is it possible to find different topologies? I am thinking, for example, about a 2-regular graph with 4 nodes where $C_4$ seems to be the only topology. Is it right?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you sure topology is the word you are looking for? I think you mean to say, for a $k$-regular graph with $n$ nodes, is there a unique graph up to isomorphism that satisfies both constraints? To that, the answer is no. There is no guarantee of existence nor uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such characterization.

Sometimes you find a unique solution, for example a $(n-1)$-regular graph on $n$ vertices is necessarily complete.

In some cases you have neat descriptions: Any 2-regular graph is an assembly of disjoint cycles (note that for a graph theoretical cycle you need at least 3 vertices, so $C_4$ and $C_5$ are indeed the only 2-regular graphs on 4 respectively 5 vertices).

Sometimes there are multiple distinct solutions. For example consider the bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$ and the graph, which is given by the edges of a prism with triangle base. Both are 3-regular on 6 vertices, but the latter has triangles, hence is not bipartite, so they are not isomorphic.